# Exoplayer - Change the size of exo_playback_control_view controller at runtime programmatically

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I've overwritten the XML layout of `exo_playback_control_view` to a custom one that I have.

[image]

Right now I am using the `PlayerView`

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/vh_videoviewholder_playerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

At runtime I have a button, and I want to change the size of controller view on that button click. Exoplayer automatically uses the view exo_playback_control_view.xml (I don't need to use `findviewbyid`) so I am unsure how I am suppose to manipulate the controller view.

Edit: How to get reference to the controller view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get reference to the player's ControlView you need to get reference to the PlayerView first.

`PlayerView playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);`

then using the playerView, you can get reference to any of the buttons/layout items using:

`playerControlLayout = playerView.findViewById(R.id.player_control_layout);`